# C# EditingCommands.MoveDownByLine.Execute(rTB, null);

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

The line in my title shows how I must write the command so there is no editor error, but this way does nothing. using richTextBox1.
MS show this below as the correct format

```
RichTextBox rTB = new RichTextBox();

EditingCommands.MoveDownByLine.Execute(null,rTB);
```

If I enter the above lines into the editor I get these **errors**

> errors  Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox' to
>   'System.Windows.IInputElement'    C:\Users\Brock\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\PlayListRandomizer\PlayListRandomizer\Form1.cs  284 65  PlayListRandomizer
>
> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.Execute(object,
>   System.Windows.IInputElement)' has some invalid
>   arguments C:\Users\Brock\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\PlayListRandomizer\PlayListRandomizer\Form1.cs  284 21  PlayListRandomizer

Some kind visual studio thing, I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

`EditingCommands...Execute()` invokes the `IInputElement` interface, which is part of WPF.  You should thererfore use WPF `System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox`, not Windows Forms `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`.

You could create an `ElementHost`, say, `yourElementHost`, in your form, then add the WPF `RichTextBox`.  Something like this:

```
        System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox rTb = new System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox();
        yourElementHost.Child = rTb;
```

Comment: Wow so much more to learn, thanks, I will read up on WPF, and try to expand my horizons.